# Ant call sequence for war

Tags: java, ant, rad

This is my ant build.xml for a Java Web Project. I am able to generate class files from the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project basedir="." default="build" name="manager">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/SDP"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.2"/>
<property name="source" value="1.3"/>
<path id="Web App Libraries.libraryclasspath">
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/activation.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cos.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/crypt.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/dbbeans.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ezmorph-1.0.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/fop.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/itext-1.4.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jai_codec.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jai_core.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta-oro.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta-poi-1.10.0-dev-20030222.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jaxen-full.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jcommon-1.0.17-junit.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jcommon-xml-1.0.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jfreechart-1.0.15.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/json-lib-2.1-jdk13.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jspsql.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jxl.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/quartz-1.8.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/rowset.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/saxpath.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-application.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-page.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-request.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-response.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-session.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.4.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
<path id="WebSphere Application Server v7.0 [WebSphere Application Server v7.0].libraryclasspath">
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/lib/bootstrap.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/lib/j2ee.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/lib/mail-impl.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/lib/rsadbutils.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.jaxb.tools.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.jaxws.tools.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.admin.services.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.ejbportable.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.emf.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.commonj-twm.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.vajava.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.wsdl4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.dist.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.sib.server.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.sip.container.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.sip.interface.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.wccm.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.wsadie/marshall.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.wsfp.main.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.commonj.sdo.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/was70profile1/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mq.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/was70profile1/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mqjms.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/was70profile1/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/dhbcore.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="manager.classpath">
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <path refid="Web App Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path refid="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path refid="WebSphere Application Server v7.0 [WebSphere Application Server v7.0].libraryclasspath"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.launch, **/*.java"/>
    </copy>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir=".apt_generated" excludes="**/*.launch, **/*.java"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</target>

<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>

<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>

<target name="build-subprojects"/>

<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="manager.classpath"/>
    </javac>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path=".apt_generated"/>
        <classpath refid="manager.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>

<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>

<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="build">
    <war destfile="manager.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
         </fileset>                         
    </war>                             
</target>

<target name="GetStringFromClipboard (1)">
    <java classname="GetStringFromClipboard" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="manager.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="Main">
    <java classname="Main" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="manager.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="MoveFileExample (1)">
    <java classname="MoveFileExample" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="manager.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="MoveFileExample2">
    <java classname="MoveFileExample2" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="manager.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

But If i execute ant it calls build-subprojects, init, build-projects and build but does not call war. How to add that to call sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="manager">
```

to

```
<project basedir="." default="war" name="manager">
```